# What are Bob Howard's academic credentials?

Tags: charles-stross, laundry-files

I read all of the Laundry Files books, and I vaguely recall that Bob insists on being called Doctor at some point, implying he has a PhD, probably in Computer Science.

Is this ever confirmed in any of the books, or am I misremembering?

Comment: I just did a quick search of the first 5 books (six, including the novella *Overtime*), and I don't see Bob either claiming or being referred to as "doctor" anywhere.

Comment: @JoeL. - Should'a looked harder :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bob doesn't have a PhD. He dropped out before completing one, due to a slight (*ahem*) mishap.

> Actually they didn’t. The ten-percenter thing only really applied to
>   staff with actual postgraduate degrees. **I’d never finished my PhD**,
>   much less got to strut my stuff in a silly robe, but I’d jumped on the
>   bandwagon with a carefully muted shriek of glee
>
> <sub><sup>[The Rhesus Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rhesus_Chart)</sup></sub>

He undertook PhD study at Birmingham University. It's not clear whether he took his Bachelors Degree there as well, nor whether he attained a Masters Degree (one of the normal pre-requisites for taking a Doctorate in the UK)

> I have a somewhat embarrassing relationship with Wolverhampton. **Back
>   when I was at university in Birmingham I nearly landscaped it by
>   accident. I was trying to develop a new graphics algorithm.** Planar
>   homogeneous matrix transformations into dimensions dominated by
>   gibbering horrors tend to attract the Laundry's attention: they got to
>   me just in time--just before the nameless horrors I was about to
>   unintentionally summon into this world--and made me a job offer I
>   wasn't allowed to refuse.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Fuller Memorandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fuller_Memorandum)</sup></sub>

He holds a degree in Computer Science

> THE NAME’S HOWARD, BOB HOWARD. **I’M A COMPUTER SCIENCE graduate** and IT
>   person, and I work for the British government in London, as does my
>   wife Mo, Dominique O’Brien, who is a few years older than I am but
>   still (in my opinion) a gorgeous redhead.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Rhesus Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rhesus_Chart)</sup></sub>

---

Bob has never insisted on being called "Doctor", but his girlfriend (later wife) Mo has been very touchy about it in the past. Possibly that's what you're thinking of.

> What do you bring to the table, Mrs. Howard?”
>   I grin and bare my teeth at her: **“That’s Dr. O’Brien to you, Ms. Murphy.”**
>   I glance over my shoulder at Lecter: his case is the right way round to display the sticker on its side. THIS MACHINE KILLS DEMONS.
>   “That facetious bumper-sticker sums up what I used to do for our organization – our real organization, that is. I destroy emergent threats. When I’m not doing field work, I have a PhD in philosophy of mathematics, lecture part-time in music theory at Birkbeck, and specialize in the application of fast Fourier transforms to psychoacoustic summoning systems. And I appear to be your designated line manager.”
>
> <sub><sup>[The Annihilation Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annihilation_Score)</sup></sub>